# Where ZFS configuration is saved?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, zfs

I have a simple setup:

- Ubuntu 13.04 on internal  USB thumbdrive
- 4xSATA drive in raidz spool with some volumes /tank/vol1, /tank/vol2

Where does zfs store its' configuration data - is it on member drives of zpool?
What would happen if USB thumbdrive dies and I need to reinstall it and access data on zpool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configuration is stored in the member drives.

There is also a zpool.cache file in /etc/zfs or /boot that has a copy of the configuration so that the kernel mounts zfs filesystems that it had previously known about. A zfs volume will not automatically be mounted at startup until it's imported (which adds it to the cache file).

Comment: Thank you!Does it makes sense to backup cache file?

Comment: Not really, no... If your thumbdrive dies you can just import the zpool on another computer.

Answer (score 2):

ZFS Configuration is stored on the member drives of the zpool, yes.

Sounds like you'd lose your Ubuntu system, but it's not clear what's on the thumbdrive.